# Detecting if method call / object init originated in ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to detect if a method call happens directly within a view, basically I want to deny access to call models directly from ActionView by throwing an error.

Comment: Shitty suggestion is, `private` all the methods, use `send` in everywhere but your views. Now what is remaining is your view method calls, which throws.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to allow end-users to dynamically update views, but want to deny access to initialize Models and call their methods from the views.